# Pass object in click/tapped event handler in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, eventargs

Here is my job class:

```
public class Job
{
        public string Id{ get; set;}
        public string Name{ get; set;}
}
```

And here is my ListView:

```
public class JobListePage:ContentPage
    {
        // Members
        private ListView lstView;

        // Constructor    
        public JobListePage ()
        {
            // Set members
            lstView = new ListView ();

            // Create job objects
            Job[] jobs = {new Job(){Id="1", Name="Benny"}, new Job(){Id="2", Name="Lukas"}};

            // Fill listview with job objects
            lstView.ItemsSource = jobs;

            // HOW CAN I PASS THE TAPPED OBJECT HERE???
            lstView.ItemTapped += async (o, e) => {
                await DisplayAlert("Tapped",  "HERE I WANT TO SHOW THE ID", "OK");
                ((ListView)o).SelectedItem = null; // de-select the row
            };

            ....
```

Now how can I pass the tapped "job-object" to the event?

You can see that I show a message to the user. And in there it should stand the ID of the tapped object.

Comment: You can just use the object inside a lambda. It will create a closure which will save the reference to it.

Comment: And the title is misleading, it's not an event, but rather event handler.

Comment: @Spo1ler I corrected the title. Thx.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try:

```
        lstView.ItemTapped += async (o, e) => {
            var myList= (ListView)o;
            var myJob = (myList.SelectedItem as Job);
            await DisplayAlert("Tapped",  myJob.Id, "OK");
            myList.SelectedItem = null; // de-select the row
        };
```

Comment: It works!!!!!! What am I missing here? Does the sender contain the job object? And what are you doing? A cast? Can you reference me to an article, that explains it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: this is a combination of different things. an `EventHandler` sends an `object (o)` and `eventargs (e)` in your case the sender `o` is a `ListView` therefore you must cast the object to a `ListView` to access it's properties. The property we need in this case is the `SelectedItem` property which is a `Job` and again we cast this (although I'm not sure we need to) and then access the `Job's` propertie `Id` [this is an article explaining this (Boxing and Unboxing)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) If this answer has helped you please mark it as the correct answer

Comment: perfect explanation! no more to say here

Comment: @user1 You just saved me a ton of headaches. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The following page explains exactly what you are looking for: [Selecting an Item in a ListView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/#Selecting_an_Item_in_a_ListView)

```
listView.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) => 
{
    await DisplayAlert("Tapped!", (e.SelectedItem as Job).Id + " was tapped.", "OK");
};
```

If you want to navigate to a detail page passing arguments then use the following:

```
listView.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) => 
{       
      var jobPage = new JobPage(e.SelectedItem as Job); // new page shows correct data          
      await Navigation.PushAsync(jobPage);
};
```

Comment: @arnie very happy to help