# Is there a way to send a XAML parameter along with a Tapped event?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My code uses constructs like this:

```
<ViewCell Tapped="openPRTPage">

<ViewCell Tapped="openCVIPage">
```

In the code behind I have a method for each.

But is it possible to pass some parameter that I declare in the XAML to the back end code so that I could have just one method and use the parameter to decide which page gets opened?

Comment: Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985571/pass-object-in-click-tapped-event-handler-in-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 0):

Using the MVVM pattern you could use a Command and a CommandParameter. Since it is not possible to use a Command on a ViewCell you will have to find a way to bind you event to command. Luckily it can be easily done using behaviours. There is an [official guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/behaviors/reusable/event-to-command-behavior/) on how to implement it.